# Rectangular Area Light Using In

Tags: directx, directx-9, managed-directx

I want to implement Area Light Exact like below link
http://blog.selfshadow.com/sandbox/ltc.html Using directx-9 how I should start.

Comment: Solution Please

Comment: That shader won't work in DirectX cause it's written in GLSL. First learn HLSL and try to convert it to HLSL. You will have to make some changes though

Comment: I converted and few changes in code but still enable to get the same

Comment: So how are we supposed to know the changes you made? What's your output  right now?

Comment: I implemented spherical area light today so now i m going for rectangular area light if any issue i will defiantly post